# Anti Inflammatory gel in plane cabin

Tags: air-travel, health

So yesterday I suffered a fibrillary rupture, nothing major, I can still walk properly, and I've been recommended to use [this](https://media.apotea.se/product-images/XL/voltaren-gel-23.2-mg-per-g-50-g-1.jpg) anti inflammatory gel.

So far so good. Now, I have a flight to Osaka with stop in Seoul and I would like to apply the gel in the Seoul stop. I'm a bit confused because the package sais that the gel is 50mg and I'm not sure if it counts as a liquid or not. If it counts as a liquid I assume that it would be 50ml and thus I should be able to bring it in it's own transparent bag.

My main doubts are:

- Can I bring that gel in the cabin as a carry-on?
- Can it get me into some kind of trouble in the security check?
- Does it count as a liquid?

Comment: If it says „50mg“ it us most likely the amount of the ingredient inside the gel (0,05 gram), **not** the amount of gel. The container should state the overall amount in ml somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- A gel is in the same category as liquids (https://www.iata.org/whatwedo/ops-infra/baggage/Pages/check-bag.aspx).
- Although the density of the gel is not the same of water, the difference should be mininal. It's surely less than the allowed 100ml.
- Put the tube in a clear transparent bag and you should have no problems.

Comment: That covers about everything, but I still feel uneasy about the fact of the gel being for medical purposes. Can that be an issue?

Comment: @ikerbera It is most probably an off-the-counter medication so it will most likely not raise any eyebrows.

Comment: There are no rules about medical supplies but for the use of medical syringes in flight, I see no problem. I bing gels and liquids in the cabin a lot and never had a problem (as long as they are less than 100ml and all fit in a transparent 1l bag)

Comment: @JoErNanO But even it was a prescription medication, there are no problems as long as you follow the rules. There are no rules about prescription medications for carry on luggage.

Comment: Bringing the gel on the plane will not be a problem.  Importing it into an other country can be a problem, if in doubt declare at customs. That will never lead to problems.

Answer (score 1):

You are not asking the right question, but we are here to help :) The problem is not with carrying it on board. The problem is Japan is one of the most restrictive countries bringing medicines sharing this top tier with the United Arab Emirates and maybe there are a few more countries but I can't recall any other that strict. This is the [page](https://www.mhlw.go.jp/english/policy/health-medical/pharmaceuticals/01.html) to read. While some medicines require obtaining a permit ("Yakkan Shoumei") before you leave (did I mention they are strict??), for your case the quote is this:

> When you bring your personal medicines into Japan up to the amount described below, you do not have to apply for "Yakkan Shoumei", instead the officers at customs check the amount of your bringing medicines, and then you can bring them into Japan.

So you *must* declare your gel at the border and not carry more than two months supply. To be on the safe side, not more than one, in case I misunderstand which category it falls under. One tube is safe. Make sure to carry the original box and paper it came with although diclofenac should be familiar to them but let's not count on it.

Comment: Well, I didn't even considered the possibility. I will take a half used tube to avoid any kind of trouble. Thank you!